# stripping a css file down to size

Tags: html, css

My html page is using a css file borrowed from a template that I would like to shrink in size to keep only the styles that are actually used in the webpage.

My purpose is so I can find my way around the css styles and modify them if needed. The css file is rather large and, being optimized with no white spaces, rather difficult to read. It came from a template that is far more complicated than my implementation and consequently contains much that I am not using. I'm guessing I only need about 5 percent of its content. Right now I have trouble finding the background color because there are so many different backgrounds defined by the css.

I have made a manual list of the -id- and -class- that appear in my html (about 20 of each), so essentially I'd like to extract from the original css the relevant styles for each id="X" and each class="Y" that I have listed.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405310/is-there-a-css-decompressor-online-to-decompress-my-code

Comment: There are a few tools to help, here's one: [deadweight](https://github.com/aanand/deadweight)

Comment: Flowerking, steveax, thanks a lot, useful links and good to have! as mine is just a one-time job, the  http://www.csstrashman.com/ suggested by Chris Danek is just the ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out CSS Trashman http://www.csstrashman.com/ . It should strip down all unnecessary CSS from your stylesheet.

Comment: just what I was looking for, great, thanks for the quick reply too!

Comment: A couple of things didn't come out right, probably because certain styles were defined several times, but I was able to tweak it in about 1 hour, starting from the trimmed-down version of csstrashman. Bottom line: my css slimmed down from 181,134 bytes to 5,988 bytes.

Comment: So I would definitely recommend csstrashman, notwithstanding its unconventional name. Thanks Chris.

Comment: and that can be brought down to 2,772 bytes with http://www.cleancss.com/, just in case.